# Samba doesn't work on 10.10

Tags: samba, networking, share

I have dual-boot laptop ASUS K42J (with Natty 11.04. and Maverick 10.10). Natty 11.04 was freshly installed, and then after couple months I had installed Maverick alongside (just for experiment).

I can access all my network shares under Natty without any issues (NAS, Win 7 laptop and 2 mediaplayers), but samba doesn’t work under Maverick however - can’t see any shares. 
I had used for samba in Maverick the same setup like I have under Natty.

Is there any difference between samba’s settings in 10.10 and 11.04 ?
Would be great if somebody could help me to make Maverick’s samba work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have these tools installed:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common samba-common-bin libwbclient0 libpam-smbpass python-smbc smbclient nautilus-share libsmbclient gnome-system-tools
```

Comment: All mentioned tools has been installed - unfortunatelly samba still doesn't work

Comment: Have you made a shared folder on your Maverick installation to check if you can see it from another computer?

Comment: I have 3 shared folders under Maverick: Music, Pictures and Videos. Unfortunatelly they are not visible by another devices in my home network. If you meant something different(for example, test folder or similar, just for checking), then please give me more details how to do that. I'll be very appreciated

Comment: The "Guest access" at the shared folders are checked or unchecked in Natty? An in Maverick? What is the name of the Workgroup of both systems?

Comment: Good question, to be honest I don't remember, but actually it's an important. Thanks for suggestion - I will check and keep you informed.

Comment: Yes, "Guess access" is checked on the shared folders. So, I really don't know why Samba works good under Natty and don't under Maverick :)

Comment: Try to uncheck it as some people (like me) also have some problems when it is checked.

Comment: Finally I had reinstalled Maverick and samba's issue has been solved. Most probably it was something wrong with my previous installation I guess

Comment: Glad you solved it.